# View in hasura and table field type not match

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I have a table with a enum type field "A"

I create a view from that table field "A", but then type of field "A" in view is not enum anymore

How can i make field "A" in view is enum like in table

Comment: Please show an example create statements for your enum, table and view. Where does it say it's not `enum` anymore? If I create an enum, use it in a table, then put it behind a view, the view still shows the field as that `enum`. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/GmMu8sG3)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't believe this is possible in the current version of Hasura.  I'm running into the same problem. Basically the only option is to treat the field in the view as a `Text` field.

You lose some type checking in your client but at least the data in the DB will be protected.